# Something special about Safari for Windows and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, windows, ajax, browser, safari

Is there something special about Safari for Windows and AJAX?
In other words: Are there some common pitfalls I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word of warning:  Safari on Windows does not support XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

Safari is really standards compliant.  Unless you're using some really esoteric browser features, in general if something works in Firefox, I've found it works without modification in Windows Safari.

Apple has [a developer center for web developers](http://developer.apple.com/internet/safari/), but I didn't find anything too useful there.

Comment: I'll second the "if it works in Firefox, it usually works in Safari" statement—especially for Firefox 3.

Comment: Even more so - if it works in Chrome, it 99.9% will work in Safari too, and vice versa, since they share renderers (Webkit).

Answer (score 2):

In your event handlers, instead of `return false`, use `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`. The `event` methods are the standard/compatible way, but lots of old tutorials still recommend `return`.